# Problem in keeping socket alive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I'm developing a multiplayer game using Flutter, Node.js and Socket.io.

I'm having a problem with this part of code:

```
url = 'http://10.0.2.2:5000';
socket = io.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false,
});

socket.connect();

socket.onConnect((_) {
    debugPrint('Client connected');
    socket.emit('userData', <String, dynamic>{
      'username': username,
      'role': role
    });
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Lobby(socket: socket),
      ),
    );
});
```

When I have to change the page and go to the Lobby, I pass the socket because I need the client to continue communicating with the server even if it changes the page. The problem is that when I change the page the socket dies and I don't know how to keep it alive

i searched a lot on the internet, asked ChatGPT but nothing worked.

Comment: Time to embrace a state management solution and hoist the socket up to that state.